# Where do I find the player data file? (The one that stores everything in the player's inventory)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am in a singleplayer modded survival world and I want to backup my player data every now and then in case something happens and I lose my stuff.

I did a test in a separate world (for example purposes I will call it Test world 1) and tried to copy the file in the 'Player' folder and then created another test world (test world 2) and replaced the file under the 'player' folder with the copied one from TW1.

When I went back to TW2, my inventory there did not change to match that of the one in TW1. So can someone tell me which file actually stores ALL player data or at least the player inventory data?

Comment: "player" folder? you mean the "playerdata" folder?

Answer (score 1):

The player data along with all world data are stored in the level.dat and level_old.dat files.

```
.minecraft/saves/YOURWORLD/level.dat & level.dat_old
```

If you want to make a backup you can always compress both files in a .zip file and name it something like "inventory-backup-(date).zip"

If you need to look at the data itself, you will need to use an NBT Editor. I personally like to use NBTExplorer.

https://github.com/jaquadro/NBTExplorer/releases

If you want to transfer your inventory to a completely different world, copy both files to the new world folder and, using NBTExplorer, make sure you set the seed to the one of the world in which you are transferring your data to in

```
level.dat/Data/WorldGenSettings/seed
```

Comment: Awesome! This helped me restore my inventory from a backup without restoring the whole world.